# navigation controller back button is not hidden

Tags: ios, swift, slider, uinavigationbar

in my app i am using slider so i am using this library.
https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift
but while using this i am confused in use of navigation bar.
in my appdelegate i write down this code

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller123 : MainViewController = (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as? MainViewController)!
let controllerright : drawerViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("drawerViewController") as! drawerViewController
let controllerleft : RightViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController") as! RightViewController
let controller = SlideMenuController (mainViewController: controller123, leftMenuViewController: controllerleft, rightMenuViewController: controllerright)

navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
window?.rootViewController = navigation
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and in my mainviewcontroller i add drwer by this code

```
slideMenuController()?.addRightBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: "ic_menu_black_24dp")!)
```

because i want drawer on right side

and when i select one item from drawer i write this code

```
let controller123 : RightViewController = (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController") as? RightViewController)!
let controllerright : drawerViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("drawerViewController") as! drawerViewController
let controllerleft : RightViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController") as! RightViewController
let controller = SlideMenuController (mainViewController: controller123, leftMenuViewController: controllerleft, rightMenuViewController: controllerright)

navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
```

but now issue is that i can not set navigation bar title or even i can not hide back button so how can i solve that?

[image]

Comment: have you check in demo code using : self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Add this line in your `viewDidLoad()` method of `drawerViewController`

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
self.navigationItem.title = "Your Title"
//If you want to create a custom title View then try this 
self.navigationItem.titleView = yourview
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this code  "override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)" in current view controller :

```
 navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
 navigationItem.title = "Hello";
```

hope this code will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in viewDidLoad in each ViewController that navigates from Drawer

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
 self.navigationItem.title = "Title"
```